# Webservice connections are canceled

Tags: c#, web-services, netweaver

I have a client who runs an SAP system, and my task is to connect our system with that SAP system through a web service. The client has provided WSDL files from which I have generated the according C# code, which I invoke as follows:

```
Service service = new Service();
service.Url = "myUrl";
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pw");
ServiceResponse result = new ServiceResponse();
try
{
    result = service.MyOperation(myData);
    Console.WriteLine("Result.EfReturn {1}, Result.EtMess[0].Message {2}", result.EvReturn, result.EtMess[0].Message);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception:\n" + ex.ToString());
}
```

This works in general. However, every once in a while (say: every 200 requests or so, sometimes much more often) I get an exception:

```
System.Net.WebException: Die Anfrage wurde abgebrochen: Die Anfrage wurde abgebrochen..
   bei System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   bei System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   bei System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   bei WebServices.WebService_SAP.service.MyOperation(MyData myData) in c:\Users\cso\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ServiceTest.cs:Zeile 54.
```

The weird thing is that this does not happen when using SoapUI, but I get authentication errors for every single request (which do not seem to affect the result, though) - the log output looks like this:

```
Wed Jul 22 11:19:18 CEST 2015:DEBUG:Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
Wed Jul 22 11:19:18 CEST 2015:DEBUG:Stale connection check
Wed Jul 22 11:19:18 CEST 2015:DEBUG:Attempt 1 to execute request
Wed Jul 22 11:19:18 CEST 2015:DEBUG:Sending request: POST /some/service/binding HTTP/1.1
Wed Jul 22 11:19:18 CEST 2015:DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Wed Jul 22 11:19:18 CEST 2015:DEBUG:Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
Wed Jul 22 11:19:18 CEST 2015:DEBUG:Target requested authentication
Wed Jul 22 11:19:18 CEST 2015:DEBUG:Authorization challenge processed
Wed Jul 22 11:19:18 CEST 2015:DEBUG:Authentication scope: BASIC 'SAP NetWeaver Application Server [TSE/881]'@somedomain:8033
Wed Jul 22 11:19:18 CEST 2015:INFO:somedomain:8033 requires authentication with the realm 'SAP NetWeaver Application Server [TSE/881]'
Wed Jul 22 11:19:18 CEST 2015:DEBUG:Found credentials
Wed Jul 22 11:19:18 CEST 2015:DEBUG:Attempt 2 to execute request
Wed Jul 22 11:19:18 CEST 2015:DEBUG:Sending request: POST /some/service/binding HTTP/1.1
Wed Jul 22 11:19:19 CEST 2015:DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

For me this looks like SoapUI just tries again, and the second request then works.

So I guess that my questions are:

1. Has anybody seen such behavior? How did you overcome it?
2. Is it possible that my problem is related to the authentication issue that I see with SoapUI?
3. How do I debug problems like this?

Comment: when you get `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`, there's no `challange header(s)` in the inbound response headers?

Comment: The initial `401` is correct when using SoapUI is correct - that's the way http basic authentication works. The client doesn't know that authentication is required so it performs the `POST` without providing username/password, the server responds with a `401` and the client then tries again, this time providing username/password and the `POST` succeeds. You can prevent it in SoapUI by ticking the *Pre-emptive auth* checkbox.

Comment: @mjturner: Thanks for the explanation. Do you think this could be related to my general problem? I noted that the service object has a boolean flag named PreAuthenticate, and which probably does the same as the SoapUI option you mentioned...

Comment: @csoltenborn I don't *think* so. The English translation of the error is "The request was aborted: The request was canceled." - I'd expect something mentioning authentication if it was authentication-related. Is there anything in your client's system, in particular a "short dump"? That error message would lead me to believe that something has gone wrong in your client's system (in particular, an error in the processing of your request). Is there anything in the data you're using that differs from calls that have been successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to regenerate the client's webservice code. We had before generated the code using MS's Wsdl.exe tool; after regeneration from inside Visual Studio (Add/Service Reference), the resulting code (which appears to be using a newer WS framework) works much better. We only rarely see errors like the one mentioned in the question.